# angular 6 custom directive for drop-down menu not working

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-directive

I have created a custom directive using Angular 6 to open & close a drop down menu by listening for the click event. Unfortunately, when the click event is triggered, the dropdown is not opening. I tried using logs to check whether the method is triggered. The method is triggered, but the dropdown is not opening up. Any suggestions to fix the error?

This is the directive file to open & close the dropdown menu (Manage Recipe):
[image: This is the directive file to open & close the dropdown menu (Manage Recipe)]

This is the html file where I have used the directive:
[image: This is the html file where I have used the directive]

Output of my app (Manage Recipe is the drop down):
[image: Output of my app (Manage Recipe is the drop down)]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends what the styles for open selector are.  if you have .dropdown-menu set to display:none and then btn-group.open > .dropdown-menu {display:block;} it should work.  can you post your stylesheet?

Comment: I did not  set any styles explicitly. My style sheet for the component is empty